# Is it possible to see the Data View with a picture library

Tags: 2010, picture-library, datasheet

I want to edit a Picture Library in SP 2010 it has a ton of meta data. Is it possible to edit it in a Data Sheet View or in excel or some other Data Sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no ootb solution, but at link below is a workaround with help of SP designer:
http://sharepointdiva.com/2014/09/05/datasheet-view-for-picture-library/

edit:
So here is text from page you cannot open.

From address:

**htps://SHAREPOINT/sites/SiteCollection/Images/Forms/BatchEdit.aspx**?ShowInGrid=True&View=%7BDCBF7E0E%2D60C2%2D4555%2D91C2%2DB086EE2F9FA1%7D**&InitialTabId=
Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence**

changes will be made to this link so bolded part of link will be changed.

First create a view in your picture library that doesn’t have any thumbnails, but does have the columns you want to edit. Put the URL for that view in the part before the “?”

Find the guid for your view by opening the view in SharePoint Designer, clicking on the WebPartPages web part, and finding the ViewGuid (image bellow).
[image]

Your guid will look something like this: {DCBF7E0E-60C2-4555-91C2-B086EE2F9FA1}

Replace: { with %7B    – with %2D    and } with %7D

The guid should now look like this: %7BDCBF7E0E%2D60C2%2D4555%2D91C2%2DB086EE2F9FA1%7D and will replace **this part** of the URL:

htps://SHAREPOINT/sites/SiteCollection/Images/Forms/BatchEdit.aspx?ShowInGrid=True&View=
**%7BDCBF7E0E%2D60C2%2D4555%2D91C2%2DB086EE2F9FA1%7D**
&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence.

You’ll now be able to use this URL to access the picture library in datasheet view (image bellow).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! To mark it as a correct answer it needs to be useful even when the link is dead though.

Comment: hmm link is not dead. it works fine. I will c/p result here.

Comment: The link works as far as I understand this site though answers should be useful even when links are not working. Thats why. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I just used this solution today in SPO and it worked great. Much appreciated.

Note that you can get the view GUID in the correct format, and without using Designer, just by selecting "Modify View" and grabbing the "View=" query string parameter from the URL.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.